# Flash Object slow in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox(WaterFox)

Tags: performance, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flash, apache-flex

Can someone please shed some light or point me in a different direction.

We are using adobe flash that launches an app inside of a JSP. Up until yesterday everything was running fine without any issues. Today when the Flash Object launches you can see the initialize bar where before you hardly seen it.

[image]

While working within the app as well all the operations are very slow (not much but a 2 second delay on most of the things is visible).

I have 3 browsers installed on my PC

1. IE 11 running Flash version 23.0.0.207
2. Chrome 55.0.2883.87 running Flash version 24.0.0.194
3. Waterfox 32.0 also running the same Flash version as IE 23.0.0.207

Running the app from all 3 these browsers is slow apart from Waterfox.

I deleted all the caches from the flash settings in control panel and for chrome I used the web interface (http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html).

I cleared all browser caches. We are running McCafee which I disabled.

I had a look at any windows updates that was done recently which I uninstalled.

What could be different between these? What else can be checked to see what is making this app slow in IE and Chrome?

Comment: What changed between yesterday and today?

Comment: @Clintm from an application perspective nothing has changed in months. I am more leaning towards an environment change but if that is the case it is something that doesn't impact Waterfox. I have no idea where to start debugging this. The only tool I know to proper investigate flash issues is firebug for Waterfox but Waterfox is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

The slowness could be caused by the files not being cached by the browser like they used to be. I would start there. If you reload the page and you're not seeing a 304 "Not Modified" for the swf(s) you're loading them from the server each time where they used to be loaded from the browsers cache.

Here's some more info on the subject: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Both Chrome and IE have developer tools you can load to see the http calls and check the headers and response codes.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools